# Using Ajax Request for search in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Below is the code that i want to use to search for clients in my table. When i start typing, i see in my console that i get a 500 status error. In my log, i see this error

> > local.ERROR: Call to a member function send() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function send() on null at /User/public/index.php:58)

It seems it is not finding any customer that is why it is null but i don't know what is wrong in the code below.

What could i be missing out?

**Controller**

```
  public function index(Request $request)
         {
            $query = "%".$request->get('myInput')."%";
            $customers = Customer::where('name','LIKE',$query)->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);             
             return view('customer.index',compact('customers','query'));

         }
```

**View**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
            var typingTimer;               
            var doneTypingInterval = 100;  

            $("#myInput").on('keyup', function () {
                clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                if ($('#myInput').val()) {
                    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
                }
            });
        });

        //user is "finished typing," do something
        function doneTyping() {
            var key = $('#myInput').val();

            if (key.length >= 1) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/admin/dashboard/customer/all/' + key,
                    type: 'GET',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#table").slideUp('fast');

                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#table").html(data);
                        $("#table").slideDown('fast');
                    }
                });

       }
    }
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="myInput" name="myInput" placeholder="Search...">

<table class="table" id="table"> 
<thead>
    <tr> 
    <th>Name</th>    
</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($customers as $customer)
<tr>
<td>{!! $customer->name !!}</td>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
{{$customers->links()}}
```

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
        var doneTypingInterval = 100;  //time in ms (5 seconds)

        $("#myInput").on('keyup', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            if ($('#myInput').val()) {
                typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
            }
        });
    });

    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping() {
        var key = $('#myInput').val();

        if (key.length >= 1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/dashboard/customer/search/?myInput='+key,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
                $("#table").slideUp('fast');

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // $("#table").append(data);
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        var tr = $("<tr />")
                       $.each(value, function(k, v) {
                         tr.append(
                           $("<td />", {
                             html: v
                            })[0].outerHTML
                         );
                        $("#table").append(tr)
                       })
                     })
                    $("#table").slideDown('fast');
                }
            });

   }
}
```

Comment: check this file User/public/index.php:58 publish that one !

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi, now i am able to search and append to the html table but it updates the searched data with all the data existing. Please check my update

Answer (score 0):

Well your query its basically saying that find the customer where id is equal to the current authenticated user and name matches the input! Which does not make much sens searching a name and adding auth user restriction! And not sure why you need to paginate the Customer response.

To avoid that 500 server error when customer not found I suggest you to add this :

```
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    if(!request()->get('myInput'))
    {
       return response(['status'=>'Input not provided']);
    }

    $query = "%".$request->get('myInput')."%";

    $customers = Customer::where('name','LIKE',$query)->get();   

    //since you are making an ajax call you must check first, since a view returned to ajax does not fit.

      if(request()->wantsJson()){

          return response(['data'=>$customers], 200);
      }

     return view('customer.index',compact('customers','query'));

  }
```